# How can I switch on *.class files to dependencies during build java project?

Tags: java, gradle

I want to add *.class files to dependencies of java project. I've found out in documentation such example but it doesn't work.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree('myClassFilesDir') { include '*.class' })
}
```

How can I add *.class files to dependencies of java project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependencies you add for the Java plugin are essentially added to the classpath. As you probably know, the classpath can only contain directories (typically containing `*.class` file hierarchies) or JAR files. In your dependency declaration, however, you add the `*.class` files *themselves* to the classpath.

You should be able to fix your setup by simply depending on (a `FileCollection` of) the directory that contains the `*.class` files:

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('myClassFilesDir')
}
```